# java type conversion issue

Tags: java, eclipse, type-conversion

Why does Eclipse point out the code below an error on the last "X"

```
int a = 1;
final int X = a;
byte b = X;
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

while the code below does not?

```
final int Y =10;
byte b2 = Y;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior boils down to the distinction between a final variable and a constant variable.

According to Java Language Specification 4.12.4

> We call a variable, of primitive type or type `String`, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression a *constant variable*.

In your first example `X` is initialized from another variable, so it is simply a final variable. In your second example `Y` is initialized from a constant expression, so it is a constant variable.

Java can use its knowledge of `Y` value in the second code example to decide that there is no narrowing conversion to `byte`. It is allowed to treat `byte b2 = Y` as `byte b2 = 10`.

In the first example, though, `X` is not a constant expression, so the compiler must treat it as an expression that could be potentially outside the range of `byte`, so an error is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
final int Y =10;
byte b2 = Y;
```

The compiler knows that the value of `Y` is a valid `byte` range value and it *can never change* due to the `final` modifier.

Whereas the first example:

```
int a = 1;
final int X = a;
byte b = X;
```

`a` could be any value and by the time we mark it with the `final` modifier, we don't know if it's a valid `byte` range value hence doing:

```
byte b = X;
```

will result in a compilation error.

if you were to do:

```
final int a = 1;
final int X = a;
byte b = X;
```

then it would also work just like the second example you've provided.